# basis-independent isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, multilinear-algebra

Could some one give me some help with this proof? Given the hint, I still don't have a clue about how to proceed. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This seems more like multilinear algebra than differential geometry.

Comment: Fine, I tagged linear algebra. How's that? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An element $A \in T_{l+1}^k(V)$ is a multilinear map $(V^*)^{l+1} \times V^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (assuming you're playing with real vector spaces; if you're not then use your favorite field, it doesn't matter. I assumed so because you tagged differential geometry and this resembles strongly the first book by Lee).

Fix $\omega_1, \cdots, \omega_l \in V^*$ and $v_1, \cdots v_k \in V$ and consider what you get by 'filling into' $A$:

$$A'(\cdot) := A(\omega_1, \omega_2, \cdots, \omega_l, \cdot, v_1, \cdots, v_k)$$

is something that when fed a functional $\omega \in V^*$ gives a real number in $\mathbb{R}$. Putting it differently, with $\omega$'s and $v$'s fixed, $A'$ can be thought of as a member of $V^{**}$, which is canonically (basis-independently) isomorphic to $V$. Moreover by the tensoriality of $A$ we know that the association of $A'(\cdot) \in V$ to the argument $\omega_1, \cdots, \omega_l, v_1, \cdots, v_k$ is multilinear.

Put another way, the process by which $A' : (V^*)^l \times V^k \rightarrow V$ is obtained from $A$ is basis independent and is given by
$$
A \mapsto A' \\
V^{**} \ni A'(\omega_1, \cdots, \omega_l, v_1, \cdots, v_k) \\
A'(\omega_1, \cdots, \omega_l, v_1, \cdots, v_k)(\omega) := A(\omega_1, \cdots, \omega_l, \omega, v_1, \cdots, v_k)
$$
(Notice that I wrote the range of $A'$ as $V$ and yet told you that $A'(\omega_1, \cdots, \omega_l, v_1, \cdots, v_k) \in V^{**}$. The reason is, as I stated in the comments, that $V^{**} \cong V$ when $V$ is finite-dimensional).

We'll now define an inverse to this. Assume that $B'$ is a multilinear map $(V^*)^l \times V^k \rightarrow V$. We'll define a tensor $B \in T^k_{l+1}(V)$ by
$$
B(\omega_1, \omega_2, \cdots, \omega_l, \omega_{l+1}, v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_k) 
=\omega_{l+1}\big(B'(\omega_1, \omega_2, \cdots, \omega_l, v_1, \cdots, v_k)\big)
$$

Now you have a correspondence in either direction, so to prove they're isomorphisms you should show they are mutual inverses.

Comment: Hi Blumenthal, thanks for your help. Do you mean $$A'(\cdot) := A(\omega_1, \omega_2, \cdots, \omega_{l+1}, \cdot, v_1, \cdots, v_k)?$$ Since the dimension of $V^*$ is $l+1$. Thanks!

Comment: Also, could you show me how to prove the isomorphism? I tried there is a bijective between elements in $T^1_1(V)$ and elements in $V \rightarrow V$, and them show there is a homomorphism. But I don't know the operations on each side of the homomorphism. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I am still did not get what is $V^{**}$ and $A$. Also, could you please tell me $T_1 = ?$ I don't understand why $T_1 = V**$. Thank you~

Comment: @Jellyfish I'll respond in chronological order. I meant what is written; the point was that $A \in T^k_{l+1}$, so $A'$ results from filling in the first $l$ arguments with some dual vectors and the last $k$ arguments with vectors.

Comment: $(V^*)^*$ is the dual of $V^*$, i.e. the space of linear functionals $V^* \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. It is an elementary fact of linear algebra that $(V^*)^*$ is basis-independently isomorphic to $V$, under $v \mapsto Jv$ where $Jv (\omega) = \omega(v)$ for all $\omega \in V^*$.

Comment: $T_1(V)$ in this notation is literally the set of linear functionals $V^* \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. That is, $T_1(V) = (V^*)^*$, and from the earlier comment, $T_1(V) \cong (V^*)^*$